# Create a script to block all followers on Twitter (except those that you follow)

Tags: twitter, javascript

Early last year Clayton Lambert posted a script on his blog which allowed you to automatically block users following you that were using the default Twitter profile image 'egg'.

```
var unList = [];
alert(“Processing”);
$('.ProfileCard').each(function(){
    if($(this).find('.ProfileCard-avatarImage').attr('src').indexOf("default_profile_images/default_profile") >= 0){unList.push($(this));   }});
unList.forEach(function(acc){
        if(($('.alert-messages .hidden'))){ $('.alert-messages').remove();}
        $(acc).find('.user-dropdown').trigger('click');
        $(acc).find('.block-text').find('.dropdown-link').trigger('click');
        $('.block-button').trigger('click');
});
alert(“Done”);
```

How could this script be modified to instead automatically block users following you that you're not following back?

That is, what would need to be adjusted to allow the script to detect whether or not the follow button said 'Following' or 'Follow' and then only block the users with the 'Follow' button?

Comment: The original blog post: http://blog.claytonn.com/block-remove-fake-twitter-egg-followers/